# How to send udp / tcp message from c program to Java EE 7 web application

Tags: c, jakarta-ee

1. I have a Java EE 7 web application (Glassfish 4.1.1) accesing an underlying Database (postgresql / oracle).
2. There is a 'c' application which also has to read/write/modify the data in database.
3. I do not want the c application to access the Database directly.
4. I want the c application to send an UDP/TCP message to my Java EE application and this Java EE application on receiving this message will query/modify the database and then send the data in UDP/TCP message back to that c application.

What is the standard approach to do this considering the Java EE servers (Glassfish) has to be configured in High Availability scenario.

Comment: A restricted access web service that can be invoked from C. It can be as easy as using `curl --lib-curl` to create the apropriate C code.

Comment: FYI: term "J2EE" died a decade ago when Java EE 5 was released. GlassFish 4.x is Java EE version 7 already. Please don't use term "J2EE" for Java EE 5+. It has negative associations with EJB2 API which was  extremely terrible back then and is totally incomparable with slick EJB3 API introduced in Java EE 5.

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks for reply. Now corrected.

Comment: @JanGreve - does web service works better than JCA in this case ?

Comment: Depends on your meassure of "good", OP. Given your C is probably not as good as your Java, a method that is easy to develop on the C site may be "better". Also, this seems like a use case for a web service.